# Add javascript when post is published

Tags: posts, admin, javascript, publish

I am trying to add javascript when a post has been published so that it's more noticable for my user but I can't figure out what to use.
I tryed with publish_post and save_post, but it doesn't work unless I put die; at the end of the code.
I've tryed so hard to stay out of the wordpress core code, and I really don't want to have to because of this problem...
here's my code :

```
function run_when_post_published($post_ID){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("essai");
    </script>';
}
add_action('publish_slider', 'run_when_post_published');
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: When and where exactly do you want this notice(?) to appear?

Comment: I'ld like it to appear when I publish a post or update a post in my custom post named 'slider'. When it is published I'ld like an alert (it'ld be a lightbox which would remove itself after like 3 seconds to be exact but that'll come later) to tell my users that their post has been successfully published / updated

Comment: WordPress has a built-in way of notifying users when a post is published using the default backend.

Comment: Hi, I'm very new to wordpress. What is the file name that contains this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enqueue scripts on the admin side, you should use the [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) hook. In this callback I check that are on the appropriate page (i.e. the page where you edit posts / post types), using the passed `$hook` argument.

Optionally you can check if the post is of a specific type (in case this is only for posts, pages, or a cpt).

Finally we'll borrow WordPress' in-built notice system. This produces the `?message=1`. The value 1-10 determines the notice message. (See **@Azizur's** answer for this relationship).

In this example, we only enqueue our javascript if the `message` variable is set.

We then enqueue our script, (which I've assumed is located: `[theme-folder]/js/notice.js` (alternatively point this to your plug-in folder). Then we 'localise' it with [`wp_localise_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). What this means is the value of `message` will be available in our javascript file as a property of the global object `wpsePost` (in particular `wpsePost.message`). You can then do whatever according to its value.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse50770_add_admin_scripts', 10, 1 );
function wpse50770_add_admin_scripts( $hook ) {
    global $post;

    //Only need to enque script on the post.php page
    //Optional: restirct by post type
    if ( 'post.php' == $hook  && 'post' == $post->post_type && isset($_GET['message']) ) {     
        $message_id = absint( $_GET['message'] );
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'wpse-notice',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/notice.js',
            array('jquery')
        );
        $data = array( 'Message' => $message_id);
        wp_localize_script( 'wpse-notice', 'wpsePost', $data );
    }
}
```

Then create the `notice.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

    if( wpsePost.Message == 6 ){
        alert('Post published');

    }else if( wpsePost.Message == 1 ){
        alert('Post updated');
    }

});
```

Comment: I just tryed your code and it works ! thank you :)
I'll need to change some things for my custom posts of course but I just tryed it with copy/past for now and will modify it tomorrow (it's late here). Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: On witch file should I implement this: `https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post#Description`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can have custom message for custom post_type 'book'. Note the array index 6 "Book Published".

```
//add filter to ensure the text Book, or book, is displayed when user updates a book 

function codex_book_updated_messages( $messages ) {
  global $post, $post_ID;

  $messages['book'] = array(
    0 => '', // Unused. Messages start at index 1.
    1 => sprintf( __('Book updated. <a href="%s">View book</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
    2 => __('Custom field updated.'),
    3 => __('Custom field deleted.'),
    4 => __('Book updated.'),
    /* translators: %s: date and time of the revision */
    5 => isset($_GET['revision']) ? sprintf( __('Book restored to revision from %s'), wp_post_revision_title( (int) $_GET['revision'], false ) ) : false,
    6 => sprintf( __('Book published. <a href="%s">View book</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
    7 => __('Book saved.'),
    8 => sprintf( __('Book submitted. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview book</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
    9 => sprintf( __('Book scheduled for: <strong>%1$s</strong>. <a target="_blank" href="%2$s">Preview book</a>'),
      // translators: Publish box date format, see http://php.net/date
      date_i18n( __( 'M j, Y @ G:i' ), strtotime( $post->post_date ) ), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
    10 => sprintf( __('Book draft updated. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview book</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
  );

  return $messages;
}
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'codex_book_updated_messages' );
```

You might be able to use the same hook to echo your JavaScript message, but I would not recommend doing it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll see about including it with Stephen Harris's answer tomorrow. I need to do it as it's for my end of school project and my teachers think it's something that needs to be done... So even if it's not optimal I'll do it (and probably remove it when I'm done with school lol)

Answer (score -1):

1. Add a filter to add the javascript to your admin head

`add_filter('admin_head', 'my_custom_alert')`

Then add the custom alert by getting the query var which wordpress adds to the query string when a page has been saved

`function my_custom_alert(){`

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>

jQuery(function($){

var $_GET = {};

document.location.search.replace(/\??(?:([^=]+)=([^&]*)&?)/g, function () {
    function decode(s) {
        return decodeURIComponent(s.split(\"+\").join(\" \"));
    }

    $_GET[decode(arguments[1])] = decode(arguments[2]);
});

if($_GET['message'] == '1'){

alert('this page has been updated');

}


});

</script>";

}
```